# How use the generic optimization program of Octave / MATLAB

Tags: matlab, mathematical-optimization

Sorry to bother you, but I'm fighting with the manual of Octave without any result.

I would like to maximize a function a little bit complex with some constraint :

The function is mathemathically similar to this one (I write this one to simplify the explanations) :

f(x, y, z, t) = arcsin (x/2t)/(y + x +  max (1, z/t))

with z, t between 0 and 1, x between 1 and 2, and y greater than 1/x^2.

Could you give me the code to compute the numerical value for x, y, z and t to maximize this function. From this code, I will derive how the optimisation function should be used.

It will help me a lot.

Thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use [`fmincon`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/optim/ug/fmincon.html) and *minimize* the additive inverse of your objective function. your constraint ("y greater than 1/x^2") is nonlinear so you should use the [`nonlcon`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/optim/ug/fmincon.html#inputarg_nonlcon) argument of `fmincon`:

```
% function definition (minus sign to maximize instead of minimize)
f = @(x) - asin(x(1)/(2*x(4)))/(x(2) + x(1) + max(1, x(3)/x(4)) );
lb = [1 -inf 0 0];% lower bound for [x y z t]
ub = [2 inf 1 1];% upper bound for [x y z t]
x0 = [1.5 0 0.5 0.9]; % initial vector
% minimization
x = fmincon(f,x0,[],[],[],[],lb,ub,@mycon);
```

where `mycon` defines your constraint:

```
function [c,ceq] = mycon(x)
% y > 1/x^2
% 1/x^2 - y < 0
c = 1/x(1)^2 - x(2);
ceq = 0;
end
```

you can also pass an [options](https://www.mathworks.com/help/optim/ug/fmincon.html#inputarg_options) argument to specify optimization options.

Comment: I don't know how this function works, but it doesn't output the optimal result at all. For my function it output a worst result as the initial vector I give as input (But it's not the worst result the algorithm met during the execution). Do you have any idea why it doesn't work?